# How to install java in linux mint

Tags: linux

I have installed Java 1.8 on my Linux mint system( new on the platform) help of http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/ website.
but when am trying to install another application with .deb extension. It says required Java 1.6 or higher required. 
Please tell why this coming.And how to solve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked if Java is working on terminal using `javac -version` command?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install gcj-5-jre-headless ; \
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless ; \
sudo apt-get install gcj-4.8-jre-headless ; \
sudo apt-get install gcj-4.9-jre-headless ; \
sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jre-headless
```

Comment: Some explanation on what this does would make the answer more clearer

Comment: I wouldn't recommend installing multiple versions of java like this when only one is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Java 1.8 wasn't installed properly.
Use Synaptic Package Manager to fix your problem. If Synaptic Package Manager is not installed, install it using following command
`sudo apt-get install synaptic`
Then open it from **System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager**  or from terminal using `synaptic`.
Search for **jdk** in Synaptic Package Manager and mark/unmark it allong with dependencies.
If there are broken package, you'll need to fix them.
Before hitting **Apply** , see the changes to be applied, make sure that it isn't removing other package group.